# Как изменять содержимое CardView элементов в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

**Задача:**

У меня есть RecyclerView, который я заполняю карточками, содержание которых берется с сервера. Эти карточки - диалоги.

И в этих карточках есть специальное поле - последнее сообщение. Когда пользователь отправляет мне сообщение это поле должно измениться на это последнее сообщение соответственно.

**Проблема:**

Мне как-то нужно реализовать динамическое изменение этих элементов RecyclerView.

**Подробности:**

Меня интересует именно вопрос изменения элементов в реальном времени, а не способ реализации отправки сообщений.

Если диалоги, я могу добавить `adapter.addAll(data);`, то вот как их изменять я не знаю. Причем это, как я сказал ранее, должно происходить динамически, то есть на глазах пользователя (без перезагрузки `Activity` или `Fragment` или самого приложения)

**Код, адаптер и холдер**

```
 private class RecyclerAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<DialogInfo> items = new ArrayList<>();

    void addAll(List<DialogInfo> fakeItems) {
        int pos = getItemCount();
        this.items.addAll(fakeItems);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(pos, this.items.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh=null;
        View itemLayoutView;

        switch (getItemViewType(viewType))
        {
            case 0:
                itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_structure, parent, false);
                vh = new RecyclerViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
                break;

        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (this.getItemViewType(position))
        {
            case 0:
                RecyclerViewHolder simple = (RecyclerViewHolder) holder;
                simple.bind(items.get(position));
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

}

private class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    //simple
    private TextView name;
    private TextView time;
    private CircleImageView circleImageView;
    private TextView lastMessage;

    RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
        circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        lastMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_message);

    }

    void bind(DialogInfo modelItem) {

        try {
            Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load("http://46.173.213.127/media?t=avatar&query="+modelItem.getPhoto()).into(circleImageView);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

        name.setText(modelItem.getName());
        time.setText(modelItem.getTime());
        lastMessage.setText(modelItem.getLastMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

**Добавление элементов:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++){
        data.add(new DialogInfo("lol",contacts.get(i), "lol","lol"));

    }

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.addAll(data);
    data.set(1, new DialogInfo("lol",contacts.get(1), "keke","kek"));//вот здесь я пытался изменить нужный мне элемент, но он не изменяется в реальном времени.
```

---

**Заранее, за все предложенные варианты добрыми людьми, говорю спасибо!**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

```
adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.addAll(data);
    data.set(1, new DialogInfo("lol",contacts.get(1), "keke","kek"));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что списки у вас разные. 
Первый вариант: вам надо редактировать один список, т.е. в фрагменте/активити держите список и его же передаете в адаптер.

```
class MainActivity ... {
.    ...
    private List<DialogInfo> data = new ArrayList<>();

    void initAdapter(){
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
        adapter.setItems(data);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.edit:
                editItem(1, new DialogInfo("lol",contacts.get(1), "keke","kek"));
                break;
            case R.id.add:
                addItem(new DialogInfo("lol",contacts.get(1), "keke","kek"));
                break;
        }
    }

    private void editItem(int position, DialogInfo value) {
        data.set(position, value);
        adapter.notifyItemChange(position);
    }

    private void addItem(DialogInfo value) {
        data.add(value);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(data.size()-1);
    }
}

private class RecyclerAdapter ... {
    private List<DialogInfo> items;
    ...
    public void setItems(List<DialogInfo> data){
        this.items = data;
    }
    ...
}
```

Второй вариант: реализуете методы добавления, удаления, редактирования в адаптере.

```
class MainActivity ... {
.    ...
    private List<DialogInfo> data = new ArrayList<>();

    void initAdapter(){
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
        adapter.addItems(data);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.edit:
                adapter.editItem(1, new DialogInfo("lol",contacts.get(1), "keke","kek"));
                break;
            case R.id.add:
                adapter.addItem(new DialogInfo("lol",contacts.get(1), "keke","kek"));
                break;
        }
    }

}

private class RecyclerAdapter ... {
    private List<DialogInfo> items = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    public void addItems(List<DialogInfo> data){
        int pos = getItemCount();
        this.items.addAll(data);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(pos, this.items.size()-1);
    }

    public void editItem(int position, DialogInfo value) {
        items.set(position, value);
        notifyItemChange(position);
    }

    public void addItem(int position, DialogInfo value) {
        items.add(value);
        items.notifyItemInserted(items.size()-1);
    }
    ...
}
```

Некоторые сложности будут, если вы захотите инициировать редактирование из holder'ов, вам надо будет в первом случае пробросить до активити/фрагмента вызов соответствующих колбэков, во втором случае логика редактирования в адаптере может выглядеть неуместной, и колбэки все равно будут. Особенно это хорошо будет видно на вашем примере, когда все классы у вас отдельные (не вложенные).

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо за предоставление двух разных вариантов! Решил воспользоваться вторым и все заработало!

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял Вам надо перерисовать Ресайкл. У адаптера есть метод adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() - который перерисовывает данные. Т.е. вам надо перезаписать data и потом дергать adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Но у меня не сработало, правильно ли я делаю? Дополнил мой вопрос внизу. У меня Recycler не меняется.

Answer (score 3):

Для обновления данных для определенного итема желательно использовать `adapter.notifiyItemChanged(int position)`

Вызывать перерисовку списка, обновляя адаптер `notifyDataSetChanged()` это должно быть последним, что вы должны сделать, так как это полностью рефрешит структуру списка. Это два разных класса. Данные рекомендации описаны в оф документации.

***Дополнительно:***

`CardView` сложный элемент и предназначен для отображения сложных по структуре ячеек. Также в адаптере очень часто к item привязывают слушатели, аттачат обсерверы etc, поэтому я рекомендую более правильно обновлять данные, бонус ко всему, только с помощью таких манипуляций вы можете обеспечить правильное обновление и анимировать ваши ячейки. Обновляя список полностью вам необходимо также обеспечить целостность данных, если они имеет связность или даже транзитивность, то может возникнуть визуальная коллизия, это уже зависит от реализации и правильной архитектуры.

Comment: Но у меня не сработало, правильно ли я делаю? Дополнил мой вопрос внизу. У меня Recycler не меняется.